# Was Fontane's Tay Bridge poem compared to McGonagall's at the time?

Tags: poetry, german-language, reception, theodor-fontane, william-mcgonagall

The [Tay Bridge Disaster](http://taybridgedisaster.co.uk/) is one of the most famous bridge collapses. It inspired a universally reviled (yet nevertheless wildly (in)famous) poem from William McGonagall, ["The Tay Bridge Disaster"](https://www.mcgonagall-online.org.uk/gems/the-tay-bridge-disaster). The poem secured his place in history as ["the world's worst poet"](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2006/jan/21/featuresreviews.guardianreview2).

McGonagall's is not the only poem which came out of the disaster. The German poet and novelist Theodor Fontane was also moved to write a poem, translated [here](https://www.bartleby.com/177/96.html) as "The Bridge by the Tay". This poem is less well-known. Part of that is probably being written in Germany, in German, as opposed to English in the UK, where the disaster took place.

With my (admittedly limited) search abilities I found an [article](https://www.railscot.co.uk/articles/A_German_View_of_the_Tay_Bridge_Disaster/) comparing the two poems:

> In spite of the contrast between the respective authors, it is interesting to note some parallels between the poems; the anticipation of seasonal festivities; viewpoints alternating between the occupants of the train and the observers onshore; technological achievements thwarted by malign supernatural agents. Both poems specifically mention that the train came from Edinburgh...
> <sub>(c) RAILSCOT 2021.</sub>

This made me curious whether **any comparison of this sort occurred at the time.** Is there evidence that the two poems were discussed together when the disaster was still fresh? Or evidence against this happening? I realize that one poem is in German and from Germany, while one is in English from UK - but the tragedy was reported widely, so perhaps the poems were distributed widely and shown alongside each other? Or perhaps they were not. If they were discussed together, I would appreciate some examples/excerpts from that discussion.

Was Fontane's Tay Bridge poem compared to McGonagall's at the time?

Comment: The rhyming of "Edinburgh" with "sorrow" made me LOL.